# rotating ImageView causes ImageView picture to disappear

Tags: java, android, xml, matrix

I have a `TableLayout` populated with `ImageView`s. I use these views to allow people to draw diagrams by dragging and dropping icons onto the `ImageView`s.

How this works: I have a class called `IconContainer` which is a class that gets assigned to the `ImageView` via the tag() property(`ImageView.setTag()`) I then store each property of the class as a node in an xml file. (the tag is to help me with other operations and to identify `ImageViews`)

This is what the xml structure looks like:

```
-<column columnID="1">

    <drawableID>2130837525</drawableID>

    <compTypeID>-1</compTypeID>

    <componentID>-1</componentID>

    <rotation>180.0</rotation>

</column>
```

Finally the problem. When I load the xml from the file, I want to rotate the `ImageView` according to the value in the rotation field(ex 180 degrees). But when I set the matrix, it loads an invisible `ImageView`. The icon doesn't show up at all and this is the exact same rotation method that I use to rotate the `ImageView` before it gets saved to the file, I have no idea why. Here is the code where I load the xml, populate everything that needs to be populated and rotate my `ImageView`

```
        for (int r=0; r < rowCount; r++)
        {
            NodeList cList = rList.item(r).getChildNodes();

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            for (int c=0; c < columnCount; c++)
            {
                int drawableID = -1;
                NodeList properties = cList.item(c).getChildNodes();
                IconContainer ic = new IconContainer();

                //get the drawable id
                String stringID = properties.item(0).getTextContent();
                drawableID = Integer.valueOf(stringID);

                ic.setDrawableID(drawableID);
                ic.setCompTypeID(Integer.parseInt(properties.item(1).getTextContent()));
                ic.setComponentID(Integer.parseInt(properties.item(2).getTextContent()));

                float rotAngle = Float.valueOf(properties.item(3).getTextContent());
                ic.setAngle(rotAngle);
                Log.i("customException", "angle from laoded xml: " + rotAngle);

                //Create our imageview that will act as our cell
                ImageView im = new ImageView (this);

                im.setOnDragListener(dropListener);
                im.setOnClickListener(singleClickListener);
                im.setOnLongClickListener(longListen);

                im.setMinimumHeight(50);
                im.setMinimumWidth(50);

                if(drawableID != -1)
                {
                    Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableID);
                    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pic, 50, 50, false);
                    im.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

                    ic.setImage(im);
                    ic.setName(context.getResources().getString(drawableID));

                    im.setTag(ic);

                    //rotate the icon ----------------------------> this is where the problem lays. the icon never shows up(if I take this out, then the icon shows up)
                    im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.set(im.getImageMatrix());
                    matrix.postRotate(rotAngle, im.getWidth()/2, im.getHeight()/2);

                    im.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                }

                tr.addView(im);
            }
            table.addView(tr);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was because of this line :

```
matrix.postRotate(rotAngle, im.getWidth()/2, im.getHeight()/2);
```

my `im` height and width seem to be 0 hence why the icon never showed up. Here is the solution that works:

```
matrix.postRotate(rotAngle, resizedBitmap.getWidth() / 2, resizedBitmap.getHeight() / 2);
```

I ended up using the resized bitmap that I create and use as my picture for the height and width which now works.